# Delete specific meta_keys from WordPress DB

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I recently deleted the plugin [Product Feed PRO for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-product-feed-pro/) but it left many meta_keys in my DB that confuse me when I import/export products.

How can I delete and clear all entries that start with `_woosea_` from the DB? Is there an SQL command that does this?

Comment: Maybe because this is very simple question and you should search web first because google should have like 100K answers for that

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '_woosea_%'`

should do the trick